# What is the proper way to remove a previously deployed service from kolla-ansible

Tags: ansible, openstack

I have a recently deployed kolla-ansible stable/victoria with several services I wanted to try but no longer need (designate, octavia, etc.) What is the "right" way to remove these services? I have attempted:

- `kolla-ansible -i multinode reconfigure --tags <services>`
- `kolla-ansible -i multinode reconfigure --tags common,haproxy,<services>`
- `kolla-ansible -i multinode deploy --tags <services>`

In each case I'm left with still-running containers, leftover configuration artifacts (/etc/kolla/.*.conf) and haproxy config files.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question, but I recently had the same problem and haven't found documentation about this anywhere.

The reason why reconfigure and deploy don't do anything even if you set `enable_<service>` to no is because the Ansible playbooks only run tasks involving a given service if its corresponding enable is true.  If you look at the output of your commands run with `--tags`, you'd see that Ansible isn't really doing anything with regards to your disabled service.

Since Kolla-Ansible deploys everything with containers, I've found most services can simply be removed by doing the following:

- Stop and delete all the containers running the service to be removed
- Delete those containers' volumes
- Remove the configuration and log files (under /etc/kolla and /var/log/kolla respectively)
- Remove databases used by the service you're deleting
- You can remove the HAproxy config files for each service you're removing.

I know this is perhaps not in the spirit of automating the Openstack management with Ansible, but I've done this a few times without too many problems.  I would avoid removing core services like Keystone, Neutron, Nova, Mariadb or Rabbitmq though because if you're doing that you're destroying your entire Openstack deployment anyways.

You can run the [cleanup-host](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/master/tools/cleanup-host) and [cleanup-containers](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/master/tools/cleanup-containers) scripts on hosts running your containers, but those remove everything related to Kolla-Ansible.  If you want to remove a specific service, you could modify those scripts though.  I'm aware certain services like Nova, Neutron, Openvswitch and Zun reconfigure the host too for networking but I haven't been able to find a reliable way to revert those changes, and cleanup-host/cleanup-containers don't address those either.  If you stop and delete the openvswitch containers, Openvswitch's interfaces go away on the next host reboot and that may be a viable method for you too.  Remember Kolla-Ansible loads the openvswitch kernel module persistently so that's something else you may want to remove as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with such scenario recently and I've found just these:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/kolla-ansible/+bug/1874044

https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/kolla-ansible/+/504592

Unfortunately, seems like a work already started some time ago, but no big progress has been done yet.